# Is there a way to assign a shortcut key to nautilus' right click context menu?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, nautilus

Does anyone know of a way to assign a shortcut key combination to the menu items in the context menu that pops up in nautilus when you click on a file?

Comment: Looking to create custom key combo for items that are in the context menu that comes up when you right click on things in Nautlius. I'm on Gnome 2.x.

Comment: You can check out this answer (for Ubuntu) I am not sure what else you are running http://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There already is one. It's Shift+F10.

This is a standard keystroke and works in many apps. And of course many keyboards have a dedicated context-menu key; it's the complement of the Windows key.

Either should work. Both do for me on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity & Nemo.

Answer (score 1):

You could look through `~/.gnome2/accels/nautilus` and edit and uncomment the appropriate key bindings. The bindings should be available after restarting nautilus (`nautilus -q`).

E.g. to activate the hotkey for creating a new folder change

```
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Folder" "<Primary><Shift>n")
```

to

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/DirViewActions/New Folder" "<Primary><Shift>n")
```

Comment: See `~/.config/nautilus/accels` in Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use the context menu key? Most keyboards have it beside AltGr. If you keyboard does not have it, you can use `.Xmodmap` (merge it on the fly with `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` afterwards to test) to enable a right click shortcut for all programs.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this blog post](http://mntnoe.com/2010/02/keybindings-in-gtk-applications/) giving many examples on how to customize GTK  keybindings via `~/.gtkrc-2.0`.  This *should* do what you intend,

```
binding "gtk-binding-widget" {
    bind "m" { "popup-menu" () }
}
class "GtkWidget" binding "gtk-binding-widget"
```

by binding <kbd>m</kbd> to the context menu.  (**However**, I just tried it with Firefox and it didn't work... No nautilus to test it, sorry.)  You could try other **classes**, too.